# How can I get the database data to appear when it first renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I've been working on a calendar that displays information from the database on each box if there is anything for that date. If there's nothing, then it's just blank. The problem that I have not been able to fix is that every box is empty. Then when I make a change to my code and save it, it finally displays in the box.

I get undefined for event. That changes from undefined to the actual data from the database when I just save my code and renders again like I mentioned.

Before using a database, I was using local storage, and it worked. Inside the useState for userListings I used a ternary with the data in local storage or an empty array if there was nothing. Is it possible to do that with the database? Or whats the best solution to get everything to appear?

CreateListing.jsx

```
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(0);
  const [days, setDays] = useState([]);
  const [dateDisplay, setDateDisplay] = useState('');
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const [showListingsError, setShowListingsError] = useState(false);
  const { currentUser} = useSelector(state => state.user);
  const [userListings, setUserListings] = useState([]);


 const eventForDate = date => userListings.find(e => e.date === date);
 console.log('eventforDate', eventForDate())

useEffect(() => {
    const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    const today = new Date();
    
    if (nav !== 0) {
      today.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + nav);
    }

    const month = today.getMonth()  //Gives you the month number
    const day = today.getDate() //Gives you the day number
    const year = today.getFullYear()    //Gives you the year 

    const firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);  //Gives you the date. Ex: Sat Oct 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
    const fullDaysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(); //Gives you the number of days in the month

    const dateString = firstOfMonth.toLocaleDateString('en-us', {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
    });

    setDateDisplay(`${today.toLocaleDateString('en-us', {month: 'long'})} ${year}`)
  
    let dayWithZ = 0;
    let monthWithZ = 0;
  
    // Gives you the amount of days before the first day of the month on the first week
    const paddingDays = weekdays.indexOf(dateString.split(',')[0]);   
    
    const daysArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= paddingDays + fullDaysInMonth; i++) {

      if (i - paddingDays < 10) {
        dayWithZ = ('0' + (i - paddingDays)).slice(-2) 
        
      } 
    
      if (i -paddingDays >= 10){
        dayWithZ = i-paddingDays;
      }

      if ((month + 1) < 10) {
            monthWithZ = ('0' + (month + 1)).slice(-2)  
      } 

      if ((month + 1) >= 10) {
        monthWithZ = month + 1;
      }
      let dayStringTest = `${year}-${monthWithZ}-${dayWithZ}`;
  
      if (i > paddingDays) {
        daysArr.push({
          value: i - paddingDays,
          event: eventForDate(dayStringTest),
          isCurrentDay: i - paddingDays === day && nav === 0,
          date: dayStringTest,
        });
      } else {
        daysArr.push({
        value: 'padding',
        event: null,
        isCurrentDay: false,
        date: '',
        });
      }

    }
    setDays(daysArr);

  }, [setDays, nav]);


 useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
    try {
      setShowListingsError(false);
        const res = await fetch(`/api/user/entries/${currentUser._id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        if (data.success === false) {
          setShowListingsError(true);
          return;
        }
        setUserListings(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log('try', userListings)
        console.log('days', days)
    } catch (error) {
      setShowListingsError(true);
    }
  }
    fetchData();
    

  }, [])


return (
    <>
  
      <div>
          <section id="calendar" className="flex flex-wrap">
            {days && days.map((d, index) => (
              <Day 
                key={index} 
                day={d} 
                event={userListings}
                onClick={() => {
                  // console.log("d", d)
                  // console.log("d.date", d.date)
                  // console.log("Click")
                  // console.log("EFD", eventForDate)
                  if (d.value !== 'padding') {
                    setClicked(d.date);
                  }
                }} 
              />
              //  <div>{d?.event?.title}</div>
            ))}
         
    </div>
    </>
  )
```

Day.jsx

```
export const Day = ( {day, onClick}) => {
    const className = `white no-underline flex h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-blue-500 p-1 cursor-pointer rounded-sm m-0.5 ${day.value === 'padding' ? 'padding' : ''} ${day.isCurrentDay ? 'rounded-sm border-2 border-blue-700' : ''}`;
    console.log("Day component", day)
    console.log("Day event", day.event)
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick} className={className}>
            {day.value === 'padding' ? '' : day.value}

            {day.event && <div className="w-full bg-blue-200 text-center rounded-sm">{day.event.title}</div>}

        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried using a ternary operator with isLoading in the return, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to add `userListings` state in the dependency array of the first `useEffect`:  `[setDays, nav, userListings]`. Also, log the `res` response of the fetch request. Check is it correct.

Comment: @OnurDoğan Adding userListings worked! Thank you so much! How did you know to add userListings to the first useEffect? I’m a little confused about that. I had tried adding it to the 2nd useEffect before, but it didn’t work on that one.

Comment: You're welcome! We added it to the first useEffect dependencies to mention that run this effect functions whenever `userListings` state is rendered. Without it, the first useEffect did run before the userListing state is rendered so userListings state had `default value (empty array [])` and the `eventForDate` function couldn't find any record. The dependency array means that the functions in the useEffect should be rendered whenever the values in the dependency array, change. So, we added it to first useEffect's dependency, to render it whenever `userListings` state changes

Comment: Yes, it is very clear now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `useEffect` should be rendered when the `userListings` state is changed. So, need to add `userListings` state to the dependencies of the first (related) `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
...
}[setDays, nav, userListings]); // <== Added here
```

Without adding it there, the `useEffect` was rendering independently of the `userListings` state. And when it is rendered, the `userListings` state has the default value which is defined as `empty array []`. Therefore, the `eventForDate` function returns undefined cause it can't find any record for the default state (empty array []).

In short, adding the `userListings` dependency state to the related `useEffect` fixes the issue.